# Is the Riemann-Stieltjes Integral additive in the integrator?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Consider
$$\alpha(x)=f(x)+g(x)$$ and $h$ continuous.
Is it possible to split the corresponding Riemann-Stieltjes Integral into two new integrals like

$$\int h(x)\mathrm{d\alpha(x)} = \int h(x)\mathrm{d\big(f(x)+g(x)\big)}=\int h(x)\mathrm{df(x)}+\int f(x)\mathrm{dg(x)}$$

??

Taking a look at the definition
$$S(h,Z,t_1,..,t_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n h(t_i)(\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1}))$$
for $t_i\in[x_i,x_{i-1}]$ makes this plausible, since I can write

$$\sum_{i=1}^n f(t_i)(\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1})) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(t_i)(\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1}))$$

and then taking the limit to infinite tight grid points, meaning $\vert x_i-x_{i-1}\vert\to 0$ for all $i$

However since this is obviously not a proof I wonder if anyone can help me out if this is true or not.

Comment: This requires $f$ and $g$ to be monotone, right?  And then you also need $\alpha$ to be monotone?

Comment: I think there might be issues if $\int h(x)df(x) = \infty$ and $\int h(x)dg(x) = -\infty$.  If $f$ and $g$ are both finite variation (so that the integrals are well-defined) and $h$ is absolutely integrable with respect to each of them, I think this should be fine.